# How to upload multiple solution of single project to Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web app using ASP.NET Core, React JS and Mongo Db. The app has different solution for each part like API and some services. I want to upload this on Azure.
I tried to look some video or steps how to upload multiple solution to single web app or web service?

[image: The Solution view of project]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to deploy Talent.App.WebApp to an Web App on App Service and Talent.Api to another one. All the others are just class libraries that will be used by those projects

Comment: I have uploaded all the required solution and now I am getting one error

Comment: GET https://talentcomservicesprofile.azurewebsites.net/profile/isUserAuthenticated 404 (Not Found)